# Posting data using $.ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below ajax request

```
var data = { ID: "data" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    data:data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {},
    error: function (response) {}
});
```

and I have this MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string ID)
{          
    return Json(new { isSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The issue is that in the controller the ID is coming out null. If I use formdata then it works. I cannot use formdata because it does not work with IE9. I have something working with IFrames for it but it is too complicated and kind of a hack.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("ID", "data");
```

Can someone please tell me how to make it work. And also how can we make it work to transfer files to the server without using formdata.

Comment: Can't your controller read the request object and pull out the data?

Comment: There is nothing inside the request object.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are manually setting your contentType to false? Setting processData to false may also be your problem.

Comment: You need to remove both the `processData: false,` and `contentType: false,` ajax options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$.post(url, data)
    .done(successClbck)
    .fail(errorClbck)
```

instead of `$.ajax`. It’s work well for all data objects but not for files